# How can I put the router inside the observable in the guard?

Tags: angular, observable, router, guard

I need to inject a router into my guard, but I have an Observable method returned. How can I add routing with a redirect to the login page, for example? The condition is the following:
If the isAccessToLobby method returns false, then redirect to the login page.

Method:

```
  isAccessToLobby() {
    return this.http
      .get(
        `${environment.domain}${BackendRoutes.Authentication}`,
        this.httpOptions
      )
      .pipe(map((data: any) => data.allowAccess));
  }
```

Guard:

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router, private autService: AuthService) {}
  canActivate() {
    return this.autService.isAccessToLobby();
  }
}
```

I tried to do this through a subscription, but if you do it inside a subscription, a subscription appears, but this is not what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with something like the following:

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router, private autService: AuthService) {}

  canActivate() {

    return this.autService.isAccessToLobby()
      .pipe(
        take(1),
        switchMap((allowAccess: boolean) =>
         !allowAccess ? 
           this.router.createUrlTree(['/example']) : 
           of(true)));
  }
}
```